# Laravel notification Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, notifications

I'm using [Automatically Send Tweets through Laravel Notifications](https://laravel-news.com/send-tweets-laravel-notifications) but i'm getting error `in PostPublished.php (line 66)` which is this line:

```
if ( ! $post->user->twitter_username or $post->user->id == 1) return false;
```

here is my full code in `PostPublished`

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use NotificationChannels\Telegram\TelegramChannel;
use NotificationChannels\Telegram\TelegramMessage;
use NotificationChannels\Twitter\TwitterChannel;
use NotificationChannels\Twitter\TwitterStatusUpdate;
use App\Post;
use App\User;

class PostPublished extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [TwitterChannel::class, TelegramChannel::class];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
     public function toTelegram($post)
     {
         return TelegramMessage::create()
             ->to('@lavtest')
             ->content($post->title .' http://domainxxx.com/blog/article/'. $post->slug);
     }


    //twitter
    public function toTwitter($post)
    {
        $title = $post->title;
        if ($handle = $this->twitterHandle($post)) {
            $title = $title .' via '. $handle;
        }
        return new TwitterStatusUpdate($title .' https://domainxxx.com/blog/article/'. $post->slug, [$post->image]);
    }
    protected function twitterHandle($post)
    {
        if ( ! $post->user->twitter_username or $post->user->id == 1) return false;
        if ($post->user->twitter_username and ! starts_with($post->user->twitter_username, '@')) {
            $post->user->twitter_username = '@'.$post->user->twitter_username;
        }
        return $post->user->twitter_username;
    }
    //end twitter

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
          //
        ];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I didn't have relation between posts and user and I made that now error has changed to `Undefined property: stdClass::$errors in CouldNotSendNotification.php (line 9)`

Comment: Does `$post->user` exists ? I think it's null or empty

Comment: That's because the `post` may not be having an associated `user`

Comment: @linuxartisan how to fix it?

Comment: Ensure that all posts have associated users. If that's not always true, then you will have to handle it in the code by checking whether `post` has `user` or not.

Comment: @linuxartisan ok i didn't have relation between user and posts but now i have and i get new error `Undefined property: stdClass::$errors
in CouldNotSendNotification.php (line 9)`

Comment: @SagarGautam it exist now and error has changed to `Undefined property: stdClass::$errors in CouldNotSendNotification.php (line 9)`

Comment: which property is undefined twitter_username or id ?

Comment: didn't say that's all the error gives me!

Comment: @SagarGautam here is screenshot  https://imgur.com/a/VRGUW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I removed my twitter app and created new one, now everything is working.